# Integrated Development Environment for web application development

Tags: ide, web

I just wanted your opinion on which Integrated Development Environment you think I should use for web application development.

It's a client side application and I'm using the classic HTML, CSS, and JS, along with the AngularJS MVC front end web application development framework.

Comment: If you really want to receive recommendations, then you have to submit a bit more information instead of "IDE for web". Like what kind of project do you want to work with, programming language etc.

Comment: ... client side or server?

Comment: It's a client side application and I'm using the classic HTML, CSS, and JS, along with the AngularJS MVC front end web application development framework.

Comment: Much too vague and too broad. On this site you list your specific needs and criteria by which you would decide on a software product. Then we suggest products that might fit those needs.

Comment: I would say that it is on-topic with that comment, and will edit the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I am using [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers), because I use it for other languages.

> Tools for JavaScript developers creating Web applications, including a JavaScript IDE, tools for JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and XML.

But I also used and liked [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), which has a "live preview" feature, where changed to the code are reflected instantly in the browser.

> Inline Editors
>
> Instead of jumping between file tabs, Brackets lets you open a window into the code you care about most. Want to work on the CSS that applies to a specific ID? Put your mouse cursor on that ID, push Command / Ctrl+E and Brackets will show you all the CSS selectors with that ID in an inline window so you can work on your code side-by-side without any popups.
>
> Live Preview
>
> Get a real-time connection to your browser. Make changes to CSS and HTML and you'll instantly see those changes on screen. Also see where your CSS selector is being applied in the browser by simply putting your cursor on it. It's the power of a code editor with the convenience of in-browser dev tools.
>
> Preprocessor Support
>
> Work with preprocessors in a whole new way. We know how important preprocessors are to your workflow. That’s why we want to make Brackets the best code editor for preprocessors out there. With Brackets you can use Quick Edit and Live Highlight with your LESS and SCSS files which will make working with them easier than ever